# Using Persistent XML in Windows store app

Tags: xml, windows, windows-runtime, store

I have been making an app for my own tablet to learn some language (Chinese) vocabulary.

For that, i have used an xml file that is included in the project. I don't create that file when i launch the app but i want to modify it which of course the sandbox doesn't let me do ...

I get very confused about File handling on that platform, such action is actually very basic and often encountered but has been made quite hard and confusing.

So, my question is simple, what can i do ? Because i have read that i can use the applicationdata folder etc... but then, the file isn't present in that folder when i deploy the app and also, i don't want to lose any of the modification made by the user (me) when i do my learning sessions ... as it modify a few information inside the node of the xml. Also it's confusing as, when you want to do that for any app, you're not gonna ask the user to copy/paste some file to the applicationdata folder

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should copy the file to it's local data folder or just save the changes/delta to a file it can modify.

Comment: Well, i was afraid of that. What if i want to add node to the original file, not just the user file, to keep it up to date ? It really is just like a local database. Hell, this case is just like the "helloworld" of the database ...

Comment: Treat your installed location file as an initializer of your database. Your database is actually stored in local data folder.